# Nolan, not available as Grid field

Tags: nolan

I've installed Nolan 2.5.1 in EE 2.9.2.  It's showing up ok in Addons > Plugins, but with the wrong version number.  It's showing as version 1.0 .  It's also not showing up as an option as an option under data type when I set up a Grid Field type:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Simple answer in the end, forgot to install the field type as well.